# Disarming guards while rescuing pirates side objective not registering

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In sequence 3 memory 2, one of the side objectives is to disarm and kill 3 guards while attempting to rescue the pirates. I have disarmed numerous guards in combat while doing this mission, but I receive no credit for this. Am I doing something wrong or is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: One thing that constantly trips me up about what the game considers a "disarm" - you have to be fighting bare-fisted in order to do a "disarm."  You can technically disarm enemies with the hidden blade, etc, equipped, but the game doesn't count this (and never explains it, :()

Answer (score 3):

By disarming they mean taking the guards weapon and ultimately killing them with it.  This can be done by disarming them with bare-hands equipped.  When you counter and disarm, with bare-hands, Kenway will take the guards weapon and then you can kill them with their own weapon(at least that's what I prefer to do).